# Strange NodeJS with Express and EJS looping mystery

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, embedded-javascript

I have some JSON I'm passing to a partial view.

```
{
"0": {
    "storename": "Park plaza",
    "prediction": "Retail Sites",
    "probability": 0.851005
     },
"1": {
    "storename": "Emory Mills",
    "prediction": "Retail Sites",
    "probability": 0.851005744010425
     },
"2": {
    "storename": "Potamac Heights",
    "prediction": "Retail Sites",
    "probability": 0.851005744010425
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the loop.

```
<% for(var i=0; i < tabledata.length; i++) { %>
<tr>
    <td><%= tabledata[i].storename %></td>
    <td><%= tabledata[i].prediction %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

I'm curious as to why this doesn't work, but without a loop, it does.

```
<tr>
    <td><%- tabledata["0"].storename %></td>
    <td><%- tabledata["0"].prediction %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><%- tabledata["1"].storename %></td>
    <td><%- tabledata["1"].prediction %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><%- tabledata["2"].storename %></td>
    <td><%- tabledata["3"].prediction %></td>
</tr>
```

I realized that even without the loop, I needed the numbers as strings. However, even when I put i.toString() in the loop, it says that there is a typeerror. I also tried putting in quotes "", as well as single quotes '' but that also didn't work.

Also, the errors I see are Syntax error, unexpected token ILLEGAL in my partial view.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you checked js developer console, any error there?

Comment: I do get a typeerror, when I make i into a string.

Comment: `tabledata` is an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop  `i` is a integer, in the other it's a string.

Amend the loop so that it is a strong and it'll work (wrap it in single quotes)

Comment: Right... but this is the part that confuses me. I tried single quotes and it doesn't work either. When I convert i into a string, it says that there is a typeerror

Comment: Look up JS concatenate string, create it like that. Also console.log the array to check how you are accessing it is correct and that the variable i is what you expect too

Comment: Console.log() is your friend